# SpriteKit - enumerateChildNode causes crash "array was mutated while being enumerated."

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, sprite-kit

I'm toying around with some SpriteKit things. I'm pretty new to `SpriteKit` so my techniques may be bad, I don't know. Here's what I'm working on:

It's basically a spaceship with shields (2D, viewed from above). There are several "shield segments" (left, right, top, bottom, each one is a `SKShapeNode`) and then there are "phaser" `node`s which are lines drawn from the border to the center of the device (the spaceship is in the center). I want to detect when the phasers hit one of the shield segments. I tried this using collisionMasks but it didn't work at all. So I tried my own way of detecting.

Next, my method of drawing the phasers may seem odd. I searched online but haven't found anything, really. So the way I'm drawing the phaser is by constantly replacing the path of the `phaser node`(a straight line) with a slightly longer path, each frame.

That's the method that does this and also causes the app to crash:

`incomingPhasers` is an array containing all `Phaser` objects currently in the scene. The `Phaser` class mainly contains the `SKShapeNode` called `node` and some other meta information.

The advancement of the progress of the phaser is done by increasing the `progress`attribute by a bit. delta is the time difference since the last frame (as this method is being called from `update(_:)`

`let vector` is the displacement vector used for the line drawing.

```
private func advancePhasers(_ delta: TimeInterval) {
    for phaser in incomingPhasers where !phaser.targetHit {
        // advance progress of phaser
        phaser.progress = min(phaser.progress + CGFloat(delta) * phaser.progressRate, 1)
        let vector = phaser.origin.vector(toPoint: phaser.target, fraction: phaser.progress)

        // create new path
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: phaser.origin)
        path.addLine(to: phaser.origin + vector)
        phaser.node.path = path.cgPath

        // check collision
        let phaserPoint = path.currentPoint
        enumerateChildNodes(withName: "shieldSegment", using: { (node, stop) in
            if let node = node as? ShieldSegmentNode {
                if node.contains(phaserPoint) {

                    // collision
                    phaser.targetHit = true

                }
            }
        })
    }
}
```

`enumerateChildNodes` causes the app to crash when I add many phasers to the array:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** Collection <__NSArrayM: 0x17404ce40> was mutated while being enumerated.'

I'm not sure what I can do here. I have to cycle through the shield segment nodes, but this keeps crashing.

Does this have something to do with thread safety? Do I need to make it thread safe? If so, how?

Thank you!

If you need any more information or code, tell me. I can't post everything here, it's way too much code.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot mutate (change, add or remove items) in a collection while it is being enumerated. Hard to tell you more about how to fix it with out more details in your code. Some thing is mutating the collection in here:

```
enumerateChildNodes(withName: "shieldSegment", using: { (node, stop) in
    if let node = node as? ShieldSegmentNode {
        if node.contains(phaserPoint) {

            // collision
            phaser.targetHit = true

        }
    }
})
```

One way that I solve these problems is I have a second collection for putting items into that fit my desired criteria, then after the first enumeration, I can enumerate over the second collection and perform the necessary mutation to the first

Comment: Hm, but what? These are just reads, and The only write operation is `phaser.targetHit = true`. But even if I remove that, it crashes. I'll try to find out. Edit: It crashing even if the body of that is empty. That's strange

Comment: It must be getting mutated somewhere else, probably in a different thread

Comment: Hm, there are 2 other places where I use `enumerateChildNodes`. But I don't call them on another thread. All of them are called from within `update(_:)`. Isn't this on the main queue?

Comment: You could try putting a lock on `childNodes` using `objc_sync_enter(self.childNodes)` performing the enumeration, then `objc_sync_exit(self.childNodes)`, this will prevent anyone else from accessing the `childNodes` while you enumerate over it. But that will also cause the other accessing thread to block until it get released

Comment: I found the problem: I added the phaser nodes in a background thread. Adding them in the main queue fixes the crashes. I have no idea what adding phasers has to do with the shield segments, though. I don't change them

Comment: Great job! You did it!